# Why can each electron only absorb one photon in the photoelectric effect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, photoelectric-effect

Studying the photoelectric effect for the first time, and can't find many answers as to why the ratio of electrons to photons absorbed has to be 1:1. Is it possible for an electron to absorb more than one photon at once, even if frequency isn't enough to excite it enough and release it? If so, are there examples of this being observed, or is it theoretical?

Comment: The term you're looking for is [Two-Photon Absorption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_absorption), for instance.

Comment: Multiphoton processes do occur, you of course tend to need quite high intensities to have any reasonable chance for them to occur.